# Manually free objects on flow scope for garbage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection, spring-webflow

I'm working on a WebFlow application that runs off of a single 'master' flow. This flow stores a large number of objects on the flow scope for communication between subflows. For some of these objects, I can verify that they are no longer needed and I'd like to manually free them for garbage collection rather than wait for the user to log out.

Is there a clean way to do this, or is it a bad idea?

Comment: There's no such concept of "manually freeing" objects in Java. Just let the garbage collector do its job. You may be able to make the objects eligible for garbage collection earlier, by removing live references which you know you no longer need.

Comment: Java has a very smart GC to take care of this. Whatever you do will only suggest to the GC that the objects are no longer being used. You actually have no control whatsoever in GCollection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing you can do is to remove all strong references to the objects which are not longer needed.  You should be doing this as good practice any way. e.g. clearing collections of objects you don't need any more and close()ing resources as soon as they are not needed (even though the GC will probably do this for you)

This will maximise the number objects the GC can collect at any point in the program.

In turn the GC reduces total pause time and maximises efficiency by only running when it needs to.  Running it more often than needed usually reduces the throughput the program, unless you have a very simple workflow and a very clear point where most (say 80+%) of the memory can be cleaned up.

Comment: "by only running when it needs to. " - could you please explain this in detail or point me to a link?

Comment: @WhoAmI When there is not enough free memory to perform an allocation, a GC is triggered. Usually this is minor collection.  The CMS can also start freeing memory before the tenured space fills to avoid waiting until it fills.  This uses more CPU as a result, but reduces pause times.